# Rails association sort with case agnostic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, associations

I have a have_many association that I would like to sort so that the case is agnostic.  Currently it looks like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :studies, order: :name
```

which sorts capital letters first then lower case giving results like

```
 DP
 De
```

I'd like the sorting to be case agnostic i.e.

```
 De
 DP
```

I've been able to do this in the model method, e.g.,

```
 def studies
   account.studies.sort_by! { |s| s.name.downcase }
 end
```

Is it possible to sort in the has_many association using order: so that the result is case agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you'r using mysql

```
has_many :studies, order: 'lower(name)'
```

`lower` is a mysql function that is equivalent to downcase in ruby. 
So since in Rails you can customize the order clause using SQL fragments you essentially can use any database vendor specific functionality that you want.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem - but it's a good idea to explain why. Remember that total n00bs may well come and find this question/answer - so a quick explanation is considered Good Form :)

Comment: There you go. Thanks for the heads up.